# how do i fill in a string grid with an array of records

Tags: arrays, delphi, record, tstringgrid, stringgrid

I have the record structure of

```
  Tperson = record
// setting/declaring the record
firstname: string[30];
surname: string[30];
form: string[5];
catscore: real;
predictedgrade: string[2];
giftedandtalented: string[255];
learningdifficulties: string[255];
behaviouraldifficulties: string[255];
```

and i have used the following code to read it as an array

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
studentarray:array of Tperson;
studentarraycopy:array of tperson;
   i,j,c : integer;
begin
 i:=0;
 reset(personFile);
while not EOF(personfile) do
begin
i:=i+1;
read(personfile, studentArray[i]);
```

I would be sorting this array of records and then using this code to sort it in terms of high,low,high,low.

```
  procedure SerratedSort(var A: array of TPerson);
  var
 s: Integer;
i: Integer;
t: TPerson;
 begin
s := Length(A);
 i := 0;
 while i < s do begin
   t := A[s - 1];
   System.Move(A[i], A[i + 1], (s - i + 1) * SizeOf(TPerson));
   A[i] := t;
   i := i + 2;
  end;
  end;
```

the result of this sort will be in a copy of the array which would be used to fill in a string grid, but how do i fill a string grid using an array of records?

Comment: Don't sort the array hi/lo. Sort it normally. Then populate the gui control hi/lo. Use the algo from my answer to your last question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  so would it be lo := 0;
hi := n-1;
while lo<=hi do
begin
  yield:= lo;
  inc(lo);
  if lo>hi then break;
  yield:= hi;
  dec(hi);

Comment: Well, that code won't compile. Yield is pseudo code. Each time you hit yield, add the item with that index. And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

A String Grid has no knowledge or association with your custom Record. You will have to decide for yourself how you wish to populate the grid based on the data it represents. There are no standard operations in Delphi to place data from a Record into a Grid. This is because a record can contain many different types of data - which may not be representable via a string.

You need to research how the StringGrid works, using resources found on the internet and in Delphi's documentation on the StringGrid.

Comment: i have previously set the column headings for the string grid but how do i display the array of records into the string grid

Comment: A String Grid isn't necessarily bound to any type of data. You have to manually append rows to it in whatever fashion you need. If you know how to display the column headers, then you should be able to understand how to load rows of data too.

Comment: Long story short, you should read the documentation on how a control works before asking questions which are rather entry-level.

Comment: @Nathan Not to be a prick or anything like that, but you really should accept an answer if it solved your question. If not, then edit your question to make it more clear what answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Type
  TPersonArray: array of TPerson;

procedure SerratedSortPersons(var A: TPersonArray);
var
  s: Integer;
  i: Integer;
  t: TPerson;
begin
  s := Length(A);
  i := 0;
  while i < s do begin
    t := A[s - 1];
    System.Move(A[i], A[i + 1], (s - i + 1) * SizeOf(TPerson));
    A[i] := t;
    i := i + 2;
  end;
end;

procedure SortPersons(var AArray: TPersonArray);
var {Basically the same as that posted by Marko Paunovic}
  i: Integer; 
  j: Integer;
  t: TPerson;
begin
  for i := Low(AArray) to High(AArray) - 1 do begin
    for j := i + 1 to High(AArray) do begin
      if AArray[i] < AArray[j] then begin
        t := AArray[i];
        AArray[i] := AArray[j];
        AArray[j] := t;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CopyPersons(const AOriginal: TPersonArray; out ACopy: TPersonArray);
var
  s: Integer;
begin
  s := Length(AOriginal);
  SetLength(ACopy, s);
  System.Move(AOriginal[0], ACopy[0], s * SizeOf(TPerson));
end;
```

Your program flow should be like this:

```
ReadPersonsFromFile(FPersons); {do this somewhere else and keep it. So that you don't read from disk every time you need this data}
```

Then in a procedure:

```
CopyPersons(FPersons, FPersonsCopy);
SortPersons(FPersonsCopy);
SerratedSortPersons(FPersonsCopy);
FillGridWithpersons(FPersonsCopy);
```

Comment: operator not applicable to this operand   if AArray[i] < AArray[j] then begin

Comment: You have to modify that to suit to your taste. IOW, if you're comparing 'CatScore's, it would be AArray[i].CatScore < AArray[j].CatScore. If, OTOH, you want to compare strings, you would use CompareText() or AnsiCompareText() etc. {Refer to string comparison functions for more details.}

Comment: ah okay thanks, also where has the Fpersons come from ? where do i delcare this. it doesnt like readpersonsfromfile and fillgridwithpersons as well

Comment: @Nathan, you have declared variables `studentarray` and `studentarraycopy` whose are `array of TPerson` in your question. Sorry, but are you sure you know, what you are doing ? Programming is not just about copy/pasting of what someone code for you with no effort of understanding.

Comment: Nathan, my 'FPersons' is the same as your 'studentarray'; and my 'FPersonsCopy' is your 'studentarraycopy'. The reason I put an 'F' prefix to them is to indicate that they (well, at least 'FPersons') should be in the private section of your form. I have done this also to prevent you from simply doing a copy/paste :)

Comment: TLama, I don't know how old Nathan is (or how familiar he is with Delphi/Pascal); but vaguely remembering how frustrated I felt when I first touched Pascal (30++ years ago), I am inclined to make life a little easy for him. Who knows, he may turn out to decide to like and work with Delphi/Pascal too.

Comment: oh and for the record im a 17 yr old student with no previous programming experience so sorry if it gets frustrating for you guys

Comment: This is the code i have with the replaced variable  CopyPersons(studentarray, studentarrayCopy);
  SortPersons(studentarrayCopy);
  SerratedSortPersons(studentarrayCopy);
  FillGrid(studentarrayCopy); but im getting errors with tpersonarry and dynamic arrays

Comment: @Adem, you might be; at the time when there was no Internet and almost no books about Pascal programming. But not these days. If I would learn Pascal/Delphi (in reality, I wouldn't), I would choose simpler task for learning and go through it step by step. Asking questions here is fine if you know basics, but not if you don't, since all the people here may suggest something different, something new, which just makes you more confused than if you'd follow e.g. a book written by one person. Sorry, but all of this sounds to me like a homework assignment, or a bad start for learning programming.

Comment: Even putting programming aside, if you always ask someone how to do something, will you ever understand how it works? Compare it to automotive mechanics. Sure, someone can show you how to install an alternator, but would you understand how that alternator is actually working? Would you know how to install one in a completely different car?